# Visualization with rtabmap

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rtabmap, should we always include the rtabmapviz node along with the rtabmap node?

I had an experience like, I forgot to remap my odom topic in rtabmapviz parameters and the robot did not detect any loop closures. When I included that, the robot detects loop closures really well.

I do not understand how this happens. Isn't rtabmapviz supposed to be aiding with visualization only?

I'm a complete beginner and I would really appreciate if you can give me a detailed explanation.

Thank you..!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357079/visualization-with-rtabmap/) by [Chan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56593/chan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rtabmapviz` is like a mix of `rviz` and `rqt_reconfigure` functionalities specific to `rtabmap`, it is not required for `rtabmap` node. Loop closures are detected in `rtabmap` node, `rtabmapviz` just shows them. If loop closures were not detected without remapping `odom` topic for `rtabmapviz`, the problem is somewhere else. Did `odom` topic also remapped for `rtabmap` node? `rtabmap` node shows by default an update log at 1 Hz in terminal when running.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56593/chan/) on 2020-07-15**:
odom topic was remapped in rtabmap node already. I'm not sure how that really worked just by changing in rtabmapviz. I think there might be some problem with GPU.